# Processing failed in itunesconnect

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7.2

I had archieved the xcode project and uploaded it into itunes connect. This is 5 time uploading, for internal testing. It shows the following error
[image: Red exclamation mark]

I don't have any idea that why the error are showing, i'm using Xcode 7.2 . Can any one help to resolve this error, i stuck for more than a day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with Application Loader.
sometimes i faced same issue with Xcode7.2 then will try upload app with Application Loader. it's worked fine.

- For uploading app with Application Loader ....

**Step-1)** First create IPA of your App.and Export your IPA which is created with **iOS App Store Deployment.**
[image]
**Step-2)** Right Click on XCode(from dock) >> Open Developer tool >> Application Loader[image] 
**Step-3)** Choose IPA (which is saved for iOS App Store Deployment) and Next to upload. it will be take some small time and after few mins it will be show on itunes connect.
[image]
after few mins it will be show on itunes connect.it is very easy and faster uploding compare to xcode. Hope it Helps you!.

Comment: AppLoader is better than Xcode for uploading binary I think.. I also have been using AppLoader for months since IDK why since that day I can't upload with Xcode anymore..

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf  issue faces many people because some internal updates on iTunesConnect our binary is not updated properly.

Comment: Right now the same for me...both Application Loader and XCode failing

Comment: I am having the same issue at this time.

Comment: @Vvk check my answer its currently a known bug

Comment: It appears that this problem can also arise if you have 2FA enabled for your Apple ID.

Answer (score 2):

its currently a bug, many dev are facing it.
Also you can follow it [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/)