# Update app to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I got this error when uploading my build in iTunes Connect:

[image: Error:]

```
iTunes Store operation failed.
This action could not completed. Try again.
```

I tried, and tried, but nothing.

The steps I have done are:

XCode
-> Product
-> Archive
-> Upload to App Store
-> Error

For programming, I use C# and I use Unity to build for XCode.

There are no errors when I compile the build; the error happens only when I upload it to the App Store.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004607/processing-failed-in-itunesconnect/36004953#36004953

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to upload your app with **Application Loader**. sometimes i faced same issue with Xcode7.2 or greter then will try upload app with Application Loader. it's worked fine. click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004607/processing-failed-in-itunesconnect/36004953#36004953) to check my ans How to upload app with App Loader.

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying

Comment: @AndreaDeBlasio welcome. if you stucked  check my another link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004607/processing-failed-in-itunesconnect/36004953#36004953

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue after updating Mac OS to v10.12 and XCode to v8.3.2. I had never had any issues in the past with deploying apps to the app store, but after the updates, my uploads repeatedly failed 15+ times over the course of a day. Closing XCode and restarting my macbook did not resolve the issue. The uploads typically failed in the "Authenticating with iTunes" step.

Long story short, I ended up disabling two-factor authentication for my iCloud account and my app uploaded without an error the first try. I believe there is a bug with Apple resulting in two-factor authentication breaking the iTunesConnect upload process. Here are the steps to disable two-factor authentication if you think this may resolve your issue:

1. Go to https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin
2. Sign in and scroll to "Security"
3. Click "Edit", then follow the steps to turn off two-factor authentication.

**NOTE**: This is just a workaround. Ideally, Apple will patch the bug so that we don't need to disable two-factor authentication to successfully upload apps.